# Unable to login to openshift with CLI

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-4

I'm trying to login to starter openshift server. Then getting error:

```py
C:\Users\Admin>oc login https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com
error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

version of CLI:

```py
C:\Users\Admin>oc version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"4", Minor:"1+", GitVersion:"v4.1.1", GitCommit:"4b47d3394", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-05T20:42:01Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
```

"About" in Openshift 4 online:
Kubernetes Master Version
v1.13.4+81fc896

full stacktrace of error:

```py
C:\Users\Admin>oc login https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com --loglevel=9
I0610 15:30:13.242674    6768 round_trippers.go:419] curl -k -v -XHEAD  'https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com:443/'
I0610 15:30:14.731741    6768 round_trippers.go:438] HEAD https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com:443/ 200 OK in 1459 milliseconds
I0610 15:30:14.741867    6768 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0610 15:30:14.742863    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 12:30:14 GMT
I0610 15:30:14.742863    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
I0610 15:30:14.743861    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Cache-Control: private
I0610 15:30:14.743861    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I0610 15:30:14.744858    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Set-Cookie: csrf-token=Y5HTi5JEtyltd27b7VgaS3tC0jpkYk2WWHqibPSa4tRsh0TJgt0k6fzfZdQTZMawO0rLB6nLNINqNmYTAtqUPQ==; Path=/; Secure
I0610 15:30:14.744858    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Set-Cookie: 1e2670d92730b515ce3a1bb65da45062=c13f251446e70d52cfdceee5ed73bcbb; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
I0610 15:30:14.744858    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
I0610 15:30:14.745855    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Frame-Options: DENY
I0610 15:30:14.745855    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
I0610 15:30:14.745855    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
I0610 15:30:14.746857    6768 request_token.go:92] SSPI Enabled
I0610 15:30:14.746857    6768 round_trippers.go:419] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "X-Csrf-Token: 1" 'https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com:443/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server'
I0610 15:30:15.085208    6768 round_trippers.go:438] GET https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com:443/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server 200 OK in 338 milliseconds
I0610 15:30:15.085208    6768 round_trippers.go:444] Response Headers:
I0610 15:30:15.086206    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Dns-Prefetch-Control: off
I0610 15:30:15.086206    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Date: Mon, 10 Jun 2019 12:30:14 GMT
I0610 15:30:15.087203    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Cache-Control: private
I0610 15:30:15.087203    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
I0610 15:30:15.088200    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
I0610 15:30:15.088200    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Set-Cookie: csrf-token=nowDCVVg+iMNf9Ldc6MldQJwsIgg8Tltk5djsue2h3uZy7woy7F1b0SfTQkv1Lw2kO3cs+82mOFOgE0Io5VUGQ==; Path=/; Secure
I0610 15:30:15.088200    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     Set-Cookie: 1e2670d92730b515ce3a1bb65da45062=a7f4fcdbc17050ff7e35cf025b9ceaf2; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
I0610 15:30:15.089199    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
I0610 15:30:15.089199    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Frame-Options: DENY
I0610 15:30:15.090228    6768 round_trippers.go:447]     X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
I0610 15:30:15.090228    6768 negotiator_sspi.go:135] Attempt to release SSPI
F0610 15:30:15.090228    6768 helpers.go:116] error: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please visit https://openshift-authentication-openshift-authentication.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com/oauth/token/request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should login using `api URL`, not console URL, such as `https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com`. api URL is using `6443` port by default.

```
# oc login https://<api url>:6443
```

UPDATE:

AFAIK, `api URL` is configured in `kubeconfig` auth file by default. And you can usually login without specifying `api URL` as follows.

```
# export KUBECONFIG=/home/user_id/install/auth/kubeconfig
# oc login
```

Usually, api URL format is `api.<cluster name>.<domain>`.

Refer [OpenShift 4: Install Experience](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-4-install-experience/) for more details.

Comment: Ok, where can i find API url?
When im trying to connect 
oc login https://console-openshift-console.apps.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com:6443
, i'm getting 
`error: dial tcp 54.153.124.11:6443: i/o timeout - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running.`
There are only 2 open ports at this address: 80 and 443

Comment: Got it. And what if i have no access to kubeconfig?
I have only access to openshift online console from browser. Because its redhat test-cluster.

Comment: Then if you have `cluster-admin` role, you would look for `configmap` configured `api URL`  from `machine-config-api` project and so on. `api URL` is shown from `kubeconfig` file, logs of installation and `configmaps` of control plane.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me

```
# oc login https://<api url>:6443
```